# present mfmailcomposer in ios7

Tags: objective-c, ios7, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

In my application statusbar color is black while the statusbar text color is white, to achieve this i have set 'View controller-based status bar appearance' to 'NO' in Info.plist file and have set this following line of code in AppDelegate class to make the statusbar text color light:

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent] ;
```

In ios7 i am trying to open a MFMailComposeViewController, its working properly but the problem is that while presenting a MFMailComposeViewController the color of text items in statusbar is changed to the black automatically and right after the moment i dismiss a MFMailComposeViewController statusbar text color is getting white automatically, don't know why is this happening..

If any one knows solution please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement this method in your viewController,

```
- (UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle
{
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}
```

and call this method where you want,

```
[self preferredStatusBarStyle];
```

Comment: thanks.. it's working but to make it working i need to set 'View controller-based status bar appearance' to 'YES' in Info.plist file, which i don't want to do because doing that ruins my all other screens statusbar text color.